# Comparing current date time(live) with file last modified

Tags: java, file, date, timer

I want my program output such that, whenever it receives a text file from a client, It will print "A new file has been received!". The text files will be store in C:/Users/%UserProfile%/Desktop/ad.

The code below is to check whether a new text file has been received into the
directory.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.Timer;


public class Test {

    final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    static int count = 0;
    static File[] f = null;
    static Date date = new Date();  
    static Calendar now = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        while(true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            f = new File("C:/Users/roberts/Desktop/ad").listFiles();
            int l = f.length;
            System.out.println("There are " +  l +  " files in the directory");

            for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                System.out.println("file " + i +  " date modified " + dateFormat.format(f[i].lastModified()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output of total number of files in the directory initially = 1 and last modified

[image]

Output of total number of files in the directory after file is received = 2 and last modified

[image]

Now in order to print "A new file has been received!" I need to compare the current date time with the last modified date time of the file.

This is what I did

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.Timer;


public class Test {

    final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    int interval = 1000;
    static int count = 0;
    static File[] f = null;
    static Date date = new Date();  
    static Calendar now = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        while(true) {

                f = new File("C:/Users/roberts/Desktop/ad").listFiles();
                int l = f.length;
                System.out.println(l);
                new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        now = Calendar.getInstance();
                        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                            if(dateFormat.format(now.getTime()).equals(dateFormat.format(f[i].lastModified()))) {
                                System.out.println("A new file has been received!");
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }).start();

            try {
                Thread.currentThread().join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried but it doesn't print "A new file has been received!". Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Watching file system changes is best done using the [`Watch Service`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html).** Right now you are polling for file changes, but instead the watch service uses native windows events.

First you just need to create an instance of the `WatchService` class.

```
Path path = Paths.get("c:\mydir");
WatchService service = path.getFileSystem().newWatchService();
```

Next you have to decide what kind of events you want to monitor. I think you only want to be informed when new files appear in the folder.

```
path.register(service, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);
```

Next, the `service` acts like a buffer of events. I suggest to put the processing of this buffer in a seperate thread.

```
// repeat forever
for (;;)
{
  // this will block until there's something inside the buffer
  WatchKey key = service.take();

  // 1 watchkey can contain multiple events, you need to iterate these.
  for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents())
  {
    //todo: handle events
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `while(true)` loop does not loop, so your code that checks the size of the directory works only once, and variable `l` stays the same. You block the thread forever with a call to `Thread.currentThread().join()` (current thread blocks until current thread stops, i.e. forever). The `Timer` fires once every 1000 ms, but since `l` does not change, it finds no new files.

If you want to simply watch directory for changes, instead of reinventing the wheel, you better use standard JDK class https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html